# ENOENT No such file or directory - from command line but NOT from VS Code Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, raspbian, fs

I'm writing a simple node application in Visual Studio Code for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ -- Raspbian OS; which writes reports in the form of Javascript objects to a JSON file in a specific folder within the app, using the fs.writeFileSync function like So:

`fs.writeFileSync("./reports/myFileName", JSON.stringify(reportObject));`

Now for the weird bit: whenever I start the app from the Raspbian terminal I get a 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file path' error. But when I start the same app from the in built VS Code terminal, everything is fine and it is able to write to the file no problem.

P.S. I've tried starting the app from the command line on OSX and it works perfectly. So the fact that it works when started from the VS code terminal on the Raspberry pi but not from the command line is what's got me really confused at this point.

Is there any story or reason?

Comment: Might be a permissions issues. Try running the command line with admin permissions?

Comment: Tried as admin from the command line, still no luck.